# xquery to skip a xml record based on some condition

Tags: xquery

I want XQuery code to group by on order number and  if any of status is open for the entire group then skip the XML records(complete group)

Code :

```
for $x in doc("C:/Users/XML/SFO1.xml")//records

let $a :=$x/Order_Number__c

let $b :=$x/Interface_Status__c

let $Order_Number__c := (substring($a,6,8))

order by $Order_Number__c,$b ascending
return $x
```

pseudo-code:

```
order   status
------- --------- 
123     submitted
123     processed
345     open
345     submitted
345     processed
432     processed
432     submitted
```

in the above, I need only below records to output

```
order   status
------   ---------
123     submitted
123     processed
432     processed
432     submitted
```

Comment: So what is the error you are facing ?

Comment: Can you paste your pseudo-data in xml form?

Comment: <records>
  <Interface_Status__c>Open</Interface_Status__c>
     <Order_Number__c>SADJ-00035267</Order_Number__c>
      </records>
 <records>
<Interface_Status__c>Submitted</Interface_Status__c>
   <Order_Number__c>SADJ-00035267</Order_Number__c>
    </records>
<records>
  <Interface_Status__c>Submitted</Interface_Status__c>
    <Order_Number__c>SADJ-00013268</Order_Number__c>
                                              </records>
  <records>
 <Interface_Status__c>Processed</Interface_Status__c>
 <Order_Number__c>SADJ-00013268</Order_Number__c>
 </records>

Comment: This doesn't look like your pseudo-code above; it more items and other order numbers. Plus you should add you xml in your question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have XQuery 3 `group by` support:

```
for $x in doc("C:/Users/XML/SFO1.xml")//records
group by $no := $x/Order_Number__c
where not(($x/Interface_Status__c = 'Open'))
let $Order_Number__c := (substring($no,6,8))
order by $Order_Number__c
return
  for $r in $x
  order by $r/Interface_Status__c
  return $r
```

This should work as after the `group by` clause the variable `$x` is bound to the whole group so `where not(($x/Interface_Status__c = 'open'))` should check your condition "if any of status is open for the entire group" negated so that the following return only outputs the groups which don't have any such record with an open status, i.e. any such groups are not returned or are skipped respectively.

Code with your input sample at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbv or for a tabular output at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbv/1.

Comment: i am using stylus studio to test the above code but gives an error ..like

Comment: i am using stylus studio to test the above code but gives an error like Expected "return", but encountered "group"  i try this code: for  $x in  doc("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/XML/SFO.xml")//records
let $no  := $x/Order_Number__c/text()
              let $Order_Number__c := (substring($no,1,13))
where not(($x/Interface_Status__c/text() = 'Open'))
order by $Order_Number__c
          return
          for $r in $x
         order by $r/Interface_Status__c
  return $r

Comment: @HariTeja, as you did now show some input sample I have tested the code, I had to change the comparison to use `Open` instead of `open`. Other than that, the code works, as you can see at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbv or https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbv/1. It requires XQuery 3 support as that is where the `group by` clause was introduced. I don't know which version of Stylus Studio supports which XQuery processor but there are open-source ones like Saxon 9 HE, BaseX or eXist-db that all support XQuery 3.